# Oracle Glassfish Server licensing

Tags: glassfish, licensing, production

I want to know what happens if I use the Oracle Glassfish Server 3.1.2.2 in a production enviornment, even if I don't purchase the license... I just downloaded the **ogs-3.1.2.2-unix-ml.sh** file from oracle's site (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/downloads/ogs-3-1-1-downloads-439803.html) and put on production, what are the limitations?.. will oracle block the server after a certain period of time?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Oracle's licensing and policies, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is expected to download the open-source version from https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html for personal use, but it's pretty much the same as OGS from what I can tell. OGS only a build that is supported by Oracle and you can get patches for. It doesn't seem OGS 3.1.2.2 has any enforcement mechanism for use or expiration for evaluation purposes...